# Angular 5+ Material Autocomplete with wrong position

Tags: angular, angular-material2

i am trying to do the [example](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples) provided in the angular material website for autocomplete and when i implement it in the application the options appear somewhere else and not under the input as shown [image]

i currently have the following code in the **html file**

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" 
       [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" 
          [value]="state.name">
          <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="state.flag" 
            height="25">
          <span>{{state.name}}</span> |
          <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

and this is what i have in the **component.ts file**

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

  stateCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredStates: Observable < State[] >;

  states: State[] = [
    {
      name: 'Arkansas',
      population: '2.978M',
      // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Arkansas.svg
      flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg'
    }, {
      name: 'California',
      population: '39.14M',
      // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_California.svg
      flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Flag_of_California.svg'
    }, {
      name: 'Florida',
      population: '20.27M',
      // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Florida.svg
      flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg'
    }, {
      name: 'Texas',
      population: '27.47M',
      // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Texas.svg
      flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Flag_of_Texas.svg'
    }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''),
      map(state => state ? this._filterStates(state) : this.states.slice()));
  }

  private _filterStates(value: string): State[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.states.filter(state => state.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
}
```

and in my **app.module.ts** i have the *formsmodule* and *reactiveformsmodule* inside of imports.

any idea why the options are not appearing under the input and how to fix the issue will be appreciated.

Forgot to add, this child component (autocomplete) is called by the parent component as follows.

```
<div>
...
  <app-menu></app-menu>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Fixed it, i was missing the prebuilt-theme provided by angular material. if anyone is having the same issue just add

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

to the styles.css

Comment: Still not getting it exact below input box!
(I am new to frontend)